# SSIS DTSPackageType behaviour

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, ssdt, visual-studio-2013

I created a new SSIS package within Visual Studio 2013 with SSDT BI Tools (12.04.2430.0) installed bu when looking into this package I can see that the DTSPackageType is set to DTSDesigner100. Based on [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtspackagetype.aspx) that means it was created in SSIS Designer in SQL Server 2008!!

I would have expected that the package was created with SSDT for SQL Server 2012

Did I miss a setting or what is the logic behind this behaviour?